# How to make a presentation similar to RSA animate?

Tags: images, image-quality

I have watched quite a few animations by RSA Animate on YouTube and have found many of them very informative. Here is one example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc

I am trying to emulate a style of their animation in my presentation. While I don't intend to make my presentation an animation, I would like to make a huge image out of my presentation slides. Say I have a presentation of 12 slides which I can arrange in a grid of 3 by 4 (or I can get more creative here). Then I will zoom into the image and slide along as my presentation progresses. At the end I will zoom out to a view summarizing my entire presentation.

I tried this with an image of the size 3840 by 2880. But the default Windows image viewer is very sluggish in handling the zoom in and zoom out operations. It also doesn't allow me to have enough tactile control over the image (using a mouse if I may add). Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into something from the following list:

- [demo of impress.js](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/)
- [demo of jmpressjs](http://jmpressjs.github.io/jmpress.js/examples/vacation/#/step-1)
- [Prezi](http://prezi.com/pricing/)
- [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/)